# Question about the basis of an intersection of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $ U=\left\langle\left(\begin{array}{c}-5 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}-2 \\ 2 \\ -1\end{array}\right)\right\rangle $ and $ W=\left\langle\left(\begin{array}{c}-3 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}-1 \\ -2 \\ -2\end{array}\right)\right\rangle 
> $ be vector subspaces of $ \mathbb{R}^{3} $.
>
> a) Determine the basis and dimension of $U, W$ and $U\cap W$.
>
> ...

**Solution:**

$ B_{U}=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{c}-5 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}-2 \\ 2 \\ -1\end{array}\right)\right\} \implies \dim(U)=2$

$ B_{W}=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{c}-3 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}-1 \\ -2 \\ -2\end{array}\right)\right\} \implies \dim(W)=2$

$ B_{U\cap W}=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{c}-3 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{array}\right)\right\} \implies \dim(U\cap W)=1$

**My question:** how do I get to $B_{U\cap W}$? I do not understand the solution. Could someone please explain?

Comment: 1. Show $(-3,0,1)$ is in $B_U$. 2. Show $(-1,-2,-2)$ is not in $B_U$.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. 1. - How can I show that? I couldn't find a appropriate linear combination.

Comment: What method are you using for determining whether a given vector is a linear combination of some other given vectors?

Comment: To be honest, I just try some combinations ^^. I didn't know that there is a concrete method for it. Could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: If that problem came from a textbook, that book is guaranteed to give you a procedure for determining whether a given vector is a linear combination of some other given vectors. Do you know how to solve a system of linear equations $Ax=b$? Let $A$ have as its columns the two vectors you're given in $B_U$, let $b$ be the vector you're trying to express as a linear combination, and solve.

Comment: I think the article should be **the** _intersection_ because there is only one.

Comment: @ms. let $A,B,C,D$ be subspaces of a vector sapce $V$. Then $A\cap B$ is *an* intersection of subspaces, and $C\cap D$ is another intersection of subspaces. I think the indefinite article is fine.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, yes, but the OP talks about two vectors spaces only (not counting their intersection). I was refering to the task and thought the title should coincide with the body of the question.

Comment: Since your are new. When someone give you an answer and that you think that the answer is good and correct you can can approve the question to give some credit to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint :
You write the equation :
$$\lambda_{1}\begin{pmatrix}-5 \\ 2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}+\lambda_{2}\begin{pmatrix}-2 \\ 2 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}
= \gamma_{1}\begin{pmatrix}-3 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} +\gamma_{2}\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\ -2 \\ -2\end{pmatrix}$$

And after you get a very simple linear system

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved the linear system and my solution is $\lambda_2 =-10$, $\gamma_1 =4$, $\gamma_2 = -3$. What does this tell me know? It's not the solution of the basis of $U\cap W $.